# Unknown flag: --platform during CircleCI build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, circleci

I try to setup a CI/CD with CircleCI. I have the following config:

**.circleci/config.yml**

```yaml
version: 2.1

workflows:
  version: 2.1
  build:
    jobs:
      - build-back
      - build-front
      - build-proxy

jobs:
  build-back:
    machine: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: docker build back -t efiscia/api --platform linux/ppc64le
      - run: echo "$DOCKER_PWD" | docker login -u $DOCKER_LOGIN --password-stdin
      - run: docker push efiscia/api

  build-front:
    machine: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: docker build . -t efiscia/app --platform linux/ppc64le
      - run: echo "$DOCKER_PWD" | docker login -u $DOCKER_LOGIN --password-stdin
      - run: docker push efiscia/app

  build-proxy:
    machine: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: docker build proxy -t efiscia/proxy --platform linux/ppc64le
      - run: echo "$DOCKER_PWD" | docker login -u $DOCKER_LOGIN --password-stdin
      - run: docker push efiscia/proxy
```

I need to use `--platform` because my production server have a different architecture than my OS in local.
But when I push the code I get the following error:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
docker build back -t efiscia/api --platform linux/ppc64le

unknown flag: --platform
See 'docker build --help'.

Exited with code exit status 125

CircleCI received exit code 125
```

I didn’t find anything about the error: `unknown flag: --platform`
This problem occurs only in circleci. Everything’s works fine in local.
Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

I replaced

```yaml
machine: true
```

with

```yaml
machine:
  image: ubuntu-2004:202010-01
```

and now it’s working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an issue with you using a really old version of Docker since you're using a really old image. Don't use `machine: true` as that's deprecated. Use a newer image: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#machine

Comment: This isn't relevant to the initial question, but I also just realized that remote docker (via the `setup_remote_docker` step) uses Docker 17.09 by default, which was released in 2017. You can set the version property to use a newer version: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/building-docker-images/#docker-version